# 彼女は日本の文化にうまく noun

Tags: grammar

彼女は日本の文化にうまく馴染めるのか、不安でならないようだ。 in this sentence, 彼女は日本の文化 and うまく馴染めるの phrase are noun, then why did we connect them with に particle  ..any similar examples

Comment: `any similar examples` <-- You'd like examples using 「～に馴染む」? or the structure 「～は～～か不安だ」?

Answer (score 3):

> 彼女は日本の文化 and うまく馴染めるの phrase are noun

You don't seem to be parsing the sentence correctly.

> 彼女は［日本の文化にうまく馴染めるのか］、不安でならないようだ。

Here, 彼女 is the subject of 不安でならない, "She is really worried ~~".

「日本の文化にうまく馴染めるのか」 is an embedded clause, "whether or not she can adjust to Japanese culture well". (The implied subject is 彼女.)

The に marks the indirect object of 馴染める. 「日本の文化に馴染む」 means "adapt to Japanese culture".

So the sentence as a whole means "She seems to be really worried as to whether she can adjust to / get accustomed to Japanese culture well."